# Fourier Coefficients of Polygon Functions

Tags: plotting, geometry, polygons

Polygon function for a regular pentagon sketched and defined below:

[image]

Fourier Coefficients are required for polygon functions with sharp discontinuous vertices;  $n$ can be either integer or real. In the sketches $(n=4,7,22/7).$

How to find FourierCoefficient[r[t], t, m]?

```
ri = 1; n = 7;
r[t_] = ri Sec[ArcCos[Cos[n t]]/n]
g7 = PolarPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Magenta, Thick}]
```

[image]

Comment: No question, just want to share with users.

Comment: Thanks; actually question is about finding Fourier coeffts where graph with discontinuities is okay.

Comment: If $$\text{FourierCoefficient}\left[\sec \left(\frac{\cos ^{-1}(\cos (n t))}{n}\right),t,m\right]=\frac{\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \sec \left(\frac{\cos ^{-1}(\cos (n
   t))}{n}\right) \exp (-i m t) \, dt}{2 \pi }$$ for example: `n=7` and `m=7` is: `-1 + Root[-77618104207 + 2811071592*#1^2 - 21781872*#1^4 + 46656*#1^6 & , 4, 0]/(2*Pi)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is an even function only cos-terms are needed. You can either use `FourierCosSeries` or `FourierCosCoefficient` for just particular coefficient.

```
ri = 1; n = 3;
FourierCosSeries[ri Sec[ArcCos[Cos[n t]]/n], t, 5, 
 FourierParameters -> {1, n}]
FourierCosCoefficient[ri Sec[ArcCos[Cos[n t]]/n], t, 5, 
 FourierParameters -> {1, n}]
Clear[n, ri]
```

[image]

```
ri = 1; n = 3;
FourierCosSeries[ri Sec[ArcCos[Cos[n t]]/n], t, 5, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, n}];
Plot[{ri Sec[ArcCos[Cos[n t]]/n], %}, {t, 0, 2 π}]
PolarPlot[{ri Sec[ArcCos[Cos[n t]]/n], %%}, {t, 0, 2 π}]
Clear[ri, n]
```

[image]

[image]

Nice images if only first two terms of series are used.

```
ri = 1;
Partition[
  Table[PolarPlot[{Evaluate@
      FourierCosSeries[ri Sec[ArcCos[Cos[n t]]/n], t, 1, 
       FourierParameters -> {1, n}]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
    Axes -> False], {n, 3, 8}], 3] // GraphicsGrid
Clear[ri]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Spiked polygon corners are blunted with just two terms.